# How to format timestamp field while loading parquet file to redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, parquet

I have bunch of parquet files with timestamp fields in different format. I would like to unify the formats while loading the data into redshift table. But below syntax is not working and it throws error `TIMEFORMAT argument is not supported for PARQUET based COPY`.

Any work arounds ? I can think of only one solution which is unify all timestamp formats while creating parquet file.Since I have to load 2-3 years of parquet files , so this solution is time consuming. Could any one let me know if you have any other solution OR anything missing in below syntax

Syntax :

```
COPY redshift_table_name
FROM 's3://path/to/files'
IAM_ROLE '*****'
TIMEFORMAT AS 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS'
FORMAT AS PARQUET
```

Comment: How about defining a number of Spectrum tables over the parquet files, one for each different date format? You could then query from those Spectrum tables into a single Redshift table, standardising the dates at the same time. You haven't mentioned how many unique date formatss there are but if it's only a handful then this may work for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use the Pyarrow library, load the parquet tables and then [write them back out in Parquet format](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_table.html) using the `use_deprecated_int96_timestamps` parameter. Redshift will correctly recognize those. I haven't had any luck getting it to properly recognize any other timestamp formats when loading Parquet.